# Setup Checkout Rest API for Shopify from react mobile app

Tags: react-native, shopify, rest

I am new to shopify, can anyone help me how to setup the checkout API for shopify. I am creating a mobile app with react for a shopify website using API. I tried the one in the shopify docs but it return some error.

post: https://{apikey}:{password}@{hostname}/admin/api/2020-10/checkouts.json

**body raw json**

```
    {
        "checkout": {
            "line_items": [
                {
                    "product_id": 5584792125605,
                    "variant_id": 35877399986341,
                    "quantity": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

**header**

X-Shopify-Access-Token : storefront access token

**Response**

```
    {
        "errors": "[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"
    }
```

But I've given API key and access token correctly. Is there anything else i should do( I tested this in postman)

Answer (score 0):

Using react native, you have to give the apikey and the password in the Header like this.

```
  getShopifyOrders = () => {
    let authorization = base64.encode(
      '${Constants.Shopify.key}:${Constants.Shopify.password}'
    );
    fetch(
      'https://${Constants.Shopify.admin_url}/admin/api/2021-04/orders.json',
      {
        method: "get",
        headers: new Headers({
          Authorization: 'Basic ${authorization}',
        }),
      }
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

With `Constants.Shopify.key = 'Your_api_key'` and `Constants.Shopify.password = 'Your_password'`

Note : In this code, you have to replace the ' with backsticks ;)